# How to delete hierarchy along with the object to which it is parented

Tags: interface, parent, outliner

In the Outliner, I have an object that contains a bunch of sub-objects. If I select the object and delete it, all the contained objects 'bounce out of it' and are still around. This is true whether I select just the object itself and delete it, or if I use `select hierarchy` and then right click on it again and delete all the selected objects. Either way, the child objects bounce out and are still present.

Comment: What version do you use?  Cannot reproduce the problem

Comment: Working correctly for me 2.83 > Right click delete. Try to delete blender and install again

Comment: I removed "This, like most Blender things, is stupid that I even have to ask this..." and "Blender, again, wins aware "most unintuitive, least thought out UI" award. Yay." From the question, because it does not contribute to communicating the question. If you absolutely feel you need to express your emotions you experience, please at least use the comments. This text is only noise in the question and gets in the way for the people trying to understand your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click and choose Select Hierarchy and then right-click again and select Delete in the Outliner:

[image]

Comment: Which version are you using ? I tried the same but the objects still remains

Comment: Current - 2.83.2, but I tried in 2.83.0 as well. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Oh yes it worked !! But often it doesn't work for me i guess

Answer (score 1):

**"Progress"**

[Coming in a new version soon.](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.90/User_Interface)

[image]

*Putting this up as an answer in speculation of a one choice selection option being available in a coming version*

I'm building and currently using (testing) 2.90 where a *`Delete Hierarchy`* option is available, IIRC was also available at some x in 2.8x... albeit with items like this its hard to remember... as when you see it you just use it.

Recalled incorrectly:

https://developer.blender.org/rB26c0ca3aa7f4

Also IMO a good idea to put outliner in scene display mode to see simply scene objects and their hierarchy. (More akin to 2.7x outliner)

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong was you **right clicked** and deleted.When you do that,only the main object to which the sub -objects are parented gets deleted.

**SOLVING:** Right click on the main-object from the outliner ,click select hierarchy and hover your pointer over the viewport and click <kbd>x</kbd>  to delete which will delete the parented objects along with the main object.

Comment: With no way of knowing which version the OP uses, if available use  the "Delete Hierarchy" option.

Comment: Which blender has that option?It worked for me in 2.80,2.82 and 2.83

Comment: TBH can't remember.  I'm building and using  2.90 can confirm available there,  IIRC was also available at some x in 2.8x.   Also a good idea to put outliner in scene display mode to see hierarchy.